# Configure Oauth Client 2.0 from other than console

Tags: gcp

I wanted to create or configure an existing oauth client 2.0 from other than console in google cloud platfrom.
I went through gcp client library documentation. But couldn’t find any endpoint or gcloud cli command to do that.
Could anyone help me with that?